# Где здесь речевая ошибка?

Tags: лексика

На этом изображении художник нарисовал сирень разными цветами: белым, розовым,голубым.
Ребенку зачеркнули "изображение",сверху исправили на  "репродукция"; и зачеркнули "цветами" ,исправив на "красками"

Comment: Это вопрос по выполнению ДЗ или нет?

Comment: Нет, это не домашнее задание.

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрались, но разбирались долго)  Правильное оформление вопроса. Предложение из школьного сочинения:  «На этом изображении художник нарисовал сирень разными цветами: белым, розовым, голубым».  Ребенку зачеркнули "изображение», сверху исправили на "репродукция"; и зачеркнули "цветами", исправив на "красками".  Как объяснить эти речевые ошибки?

Comment: По поводу репродукции.  Конечно, в учебнике мы видим репродукции, а не оригиналы. В то же время сочинение школьники пишут именно по картине, а репродукция  дает нам представление о картине. Поэтому в образцах школьных сочинений говорится о картинах.

Comment: О ТЕРМИНАХ. Картина. Произведение живописи в красках на куске холста, доске, листе бумаги. Натюрморт (неживая природа). Жанр изобразительного искусства, который посвящен изображению вещей (предметов, цветов, фруктов, снеди и т. д.), а также КАРТИНА, рисунок с таким изображением.

Answer (score 4):

Вариант школьника: ***На этом изображении** художник нарисовал сирень разными **цветами**: белым, розовым, голубым.*

**Правильно:**

***На картине** художник нарисовал (изобразил) сирень разными **красками**: белой, розовой, голубой.*

**Речевые ошибки**: (1) нельзя сказать: "нарисовал на изображении"; (2) картины рисуют красками, подбирая нужные цвета.

**МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ**

**[Образцы сочинений из Интернета](https://www.chitalnya.ru/work/3256993/)**

**[Большой толковый словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42)**

**ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ**, -я; ср. 1. к Изобразить - изображать и Изобразиться - изображаться. И. действительности. Больше всего затрудняло и. деталей. И. какой-л. местности. 2. **То, что изображено** (рисунок, фотография, скульптура и т.п.); предмет, изображающий кого-, что-л. Монеты с изображением герба. Подарить и. языческого божества. Скульптурное и. // Образ предмета, отражённый где-л. И. в зеркале. На стекле осталось и. пальцев.

**ЦВЕТ**, -а (-у), предлож. в цвете; мн. цвета, -ов; м. 1. Свойство тела вызывать зрительное ощущение в соответствии со спектральным составом отражаемого или испускаемого им видимого излучения; окраска. Белый, красный, синий ц. Светлые, тёмные цвета. Ткань цвета вишни, чайной розы. Игрушки всех цветов радуги. Подобрать обои под ц. мебели (того же тона).

**КРАСКА**, -и; мн. род. -сок, дат. -скам; ж. 1. Вещество, придающее тот или иной цвет предметам, которые оно покрывает или пропитывает. Зелёная к. Масляные, акварельные краски.  2. мн.: **краски, -сок. Тон, цвет, колорит.** Пейзажи этого художника отличают яркие краски. Краски осени. Краски утренней зари. Мода этого сезона предпочитает яркие краски. Броские, скупые краски.  **Рисовать (изображать)** мрачными (чёрными) красками что. Изображать что-л. безрадостно, беспросветно, обращая внимание только на отрицательные стороны чего-л.

Answer (score 3):

*На этом изображении художник нарисовал сирень разными цветами: белым, розовым,голубым.*

Далее идет долгое нудное описание, которое рекомендую пропустить и читать сразу с момента "**итак, резюмируя...**"

Ну тут несколько проблем, да. Если не придираться, то можно конечно оставить как есть, но вообще, тут несколько речевых ошибок.

Начиная с "ребёнку зачеркнули". Ну как бы да, зачеркнули, но не ребёнку, а ученику, учащемуся. Не потому что он ребёнок, ваш или чей-то, а потому что его учат писать грамотно. Он не перестанет быть чьим-то ребёнком, даже если будет писать с речевыми ошибками. То есть ребёнок тут неуместное название для описанного случая. Хотя из этого слова можно сделать какие-то выводы о том, кем вы приходитесь ученику.

Я к тому, что выбор слов, может менять то, о чем идет речь.

В данном случае, ребёнок - это неточность, потому что это не сужает проблему, а расширяет область допустимых решений. Но чтобы решить проблему, лучше её конкретизировать, то есть поставить задачу точнее лучше, чем абстрактно.

Переходя к самой проблемной фразе:

Изображение - что не так? Дело в том, не все слова называют то или иное явление, часть слов являются "референсами" то есть отсылками к чему-то еще, указывающими, например, на характер действия, а не на предмет, на отношение между объектами, но не на сами объекты. В русском языке слово "изображение" - это как раз характерное действие, а не предмет, а как предмет - это скорее кривой перевод английский слов "image" и "picture". То есть употребляя слово "изображение" в данном контексте ваш "ребёнок" начинает говорить уже не на русском, а на смеси русского с английским, это семантическое смешение и есть речевая ошибка. Смотрим словарь Ушакова, как самый адекватный из словарей русского языка, и видим что:

> ИЗОБРАЖЕ́НИЕ, изображения, ср. (книжн.).
>
> 1. только ед. Действие по гл. изобразить-изображать. Больше всего меня затрудняло изображение деталей. Изображение ужасов крепостного права.
> 2. Предмет, изображающий кого-что-нибудь, художественный образ, воспроизведение чего-нибудь. Монета с изображением герба...

Либо это действие связанное с глаголом изображать, то есть уже происходит конфликт слова "изображать" и "нарисовал" употребленных рядом во фразе, если бы "ребёнок" поменял значения слов местами, то это уже не было бы ошибкой: **на этом рисунке художник изобразил**...

То есть казалось бы синонимы, но не все синонимы могут равнозначно заменять друг друга.

Либо логика 2, если это **изображение чего-то ещё** - например герба. **На этом гербе художник нарисовал...** То есть сразу появляется тот объект, о котором идет речь, а не перенос на что-то ещё. А если оставить "изображение" сразу возникает вопрос: *изображение чего?*

Третий вариант - пойти по логике вопроса. Изображение чего? - сирени. **Изображение сирени нарисовано художником с помощью нескольких цветов: белого, розового, голубого.**

То есть замечаете, как меняется согласование, в зависимости от того, что с чем связано по смыслу? Причём я удали часть "на этом", почему вообще было это местоимение? А именно потому, что изображение не дает название объекта, а даёт лишь референс, поэтом ребёнок сказал в сухом остатке: **на этом художник нарисовал сирень.**

И мне вот еще режет глаз расположение слова сирень: художник нарисовал разными цветами сирень(а делее перечисление), а если художник нарисовал сирень разными цветами - то дальше уже перечисления не будет, потому что последнее сказанное, является главным. Название цветом же в свою очередь относятся уже не к слову "цветами" а к слову "сирень". А если главное слово цветами, то перечисление их должно идти до определяемого слова: художник нарисовал сирень белым, розовым и голубым цветами.

Ну и слово цветами тоже конфликтует с глаголом - рисовал - потому что рисуют красками. Ещё есть путаница что сирень цветы и краски имеют цвет, но цветами это вообще что - это цветы или оттенки красок). То есть подобный словесный салат говорит о том, что у ребёнка есть сложности с речью, то есть ребёнок ленится при выборе слов, используя максимально простую, детскую лексику, из-за этого создаются вот такие каламбуры, когда не ясно какие слова в фразе с какими связаны...

При этом решений у этой запутанности может быть несколько. Слово цветами допустимо в связке со словом изображение:
**Изображение сирени выполнено художником с помощью цветов: белого, розового, голубого.**

Хотя тут тоже есть вопросы, к технике рисования вообще, о чём речь идет сложно понять, но к грамотности такой фразы тоже придраться сложно...

Учительница пошла по иному пути, она просто зачеркнуло неудачное слово **изображение** и исправила его на слово **репродукция**. Репродукция - это специфический термин, это вообще любое и изображение и любое другое воссоздание оригинальной картины или другого произведения искусства. В чем минус данного метода? В том, что учитель не решила словесную путаницу созданную учеником, а заклеила эту семантическую дыру заплаткой - словом которым можно заменить. При этом путаница также сохранилась и слова "изображение, нарисованное художником, цвета, краски" так же продолжают хаотично существовать и находится в непонятной связи в голове у ученика, но частный случай был решён с помощью установки заплатки-термина. То есть ученик может выучить новый термин, и использовать его в шаблонной фразе, также заученной, но шаг влево, шаг вправо - и опять семантическая неразбериха.

**Итак, резюмируя** весь мой бред, можно подвести итог:

**Изображение - это процесс**, указание на предмет и характер его создания, а не название объекта, *изображение* тут конфликтует со словом *нарисовал*. Поэтому нужно либо "на этом рисунке изобразил", либо уже сказать изображение чего? ну либо заменить словом термином - репродукция(хотя изображение в учебнике, это не репродукция, тут тоже можно придраться).

**Рисуют красками, а краски имеют цвет** - такая связка. Можно сказать *нарисовано красками следующих цветов*, но говорить "нарисовано цветами" - криво, потому что звучит неоднозначно, то ли цветами, которые от красок, то ли цветами, которые сирени). Хотя, изображать можно цветом, но это сложнее, и какой смысл получится в данной фразе сложно сказать.

Comment: Очень интересные рассуждения, да)  Голос от меня, если что. А как правильно записать весь текст?

Comment: @Sharon что значит правильно? Тут же вопрос не в том, что правильно, а что хотел сказать ученик? Может вот это: изображение сирени выполнено художником с помощью цветов: белого, розового, голубого? А может вот это: На этой репродукции художник нарисовал сирень разными красками: белой, розовой,голубой?

Comment: Хотя втрое - это то, что хотела сказать учительница, то есть то, что она прочла в написанном учеником. А вот что сказал ученик, тут запутанности куда больше, чем понятности, нужно беседовать с "ребёнком" и уточнять, что он или она имела ввиду. Но есть вероятность, что он ничего не имел ввиду, просто пытался повторить то, что сказала учительница, но при этом забыл слова "репродукция" и "краски", то есть вместо повторения пересказал текст используя синонимы и допустив ряд неточностей.

Comment: Я и говорю – детективная история)  Откуда автор вопроса его взял? Что он хочет от нас, решить его ДЗ? Пусть так. А что хотели составители задания? А может это письмо родителей, которые не могут правильно его составить? Вот вы им помогите и запишите полный текст. А они его отправят куда следует.  И как выглядел сам-то рисунок, мне это интересно. Были на нем какие-нибудь слова или нет?

Comment: @Sharon ну или можно понять, что правильно, это любой связный текст. Можно попробовать по порядку описывать, без создания семантической путаницы: на картинке в учебнике изображена сирень, нарисованная художником... Соцветия сирени разных цветов: розового, голубого, белого. - правда тут слово соцветия надо вспомнить или знать, а если сказать цветы будет опять путаница, потому что "цветы разных цветов")

Comment: @Sharon ну я думаю, это просто мама пытается понять, почему учительница исправила сочиненное предложение и снизила оценку  её ребёнку...(не знаю, правильно ли я тут согласовал)

Comment: Это да. Тогда мы должны как бы увидеть это рисунок или текст-оригинал.  Репродукция откуда взялась?

Comment: @Sharon я так понимаю, что репродукция - это в музее, копия картины, напоминающая оригинал. А в учебнике как раз изображение, тут учительница как бы не права) изображение репродукции картины.

Comment: @Sharon 1. только ед. Воспроизведение и размножение рисунков путем фотографии, клише и т.п. (тип.).
2. Картина, рисунок, воспроизведенный типографским способом. Альбом с репродукциями картин известных художников.
3. только ед. Воспроизведение того, что удержано в памяти (псих.).

Comment: Да, много чего узнали...

Comment: @Sharon не знаю короче, насчет репродукции, смущает меня то, что в учебниках изображено, называть репродукциями... Если альбом с напечатанными там картинами - да, но когда дают сикось-накось хреновейшего качества черт знает что, это репродукцией не поворачивается язык называть) изображение чего-то там - может быть.

Comment: А как же назвать? Это картина, рисунок, воспроизведенный типографским способом.  Не оригинал же.  А какого качества – другая тема.

Comment: @Sharon ну технически, это да, репродукция) то есть это термин именно для метода воспроизведения. Но сам термин репродукция можно описать через "изображение чего-то" или точнее "воспроизведение рисунка , картины, фотографии". То есть способ изображения. Ну и тут тоже масса моментов, если это репродукция, то как там художник рисовал)

Comment: @Sharon короче ребёнок не шарит за терминологию(и я тоже) , но его как бы склоняют к употреблению этой самой терминологии. Чтобы понимать терминологию, нужно понимать процесс производства, знать технические моменты, а если не знаешь, тут и путаница возникает.

Comment: Ученик должен "шарить", для этого и учится. А вот почему автор вопроса (2 голоса!) не может правильно его оформить, я не знаю. Нужно редактировать вопрос, а уж потом за него ГОЛОСОВАТЬ.

Comment: @Sharon ну мне тоже сложно без собственно изображения описывать, а Шампар вон ничего, написал, то ли видел уже то ли еще как-то изнал, что таки изображено)

Comment: Да, веселая получилась тема, спасибо всем участникам. //   Некоторые люди все видят в розовом  и голубом цвете))  // А сирень можно включить в натюрморт?  Но тогда нужно добавить к сирени что-нибудь съедобное. Или посуду - рюмки там, кувшинчики, кувшинчики.

Answer (score 1):

> На этом изображении художник нарисовал сирень разными цветами: белым,
> розовым,голубым. Ребенку зачеркнули "изображение",сверху исправили на
> "репродукция"; и зачеркнули "цветами" ,исправив на "красками"

Вопрос, думается, должен был заканчиваться просьбой: «*Если сможете, вставьте правильные слова, да и чернил у нас мало*».

*На этой цветной репродукции мы видим выполненный художником живописный/акварельный этюд с сиренью разных оттенков — от розовых до голубых.*

*Даже по репродукции натюрморта видно, насколько правдиво художник смог передать  красками разные (от розовых до голубых) оттенки цвета сирени.*

Comment: PS (навеяно Sharon: «...им нужен правильный ответ, по грамматике и пунктуации?» и «хотелось бы. конечно, увидеть правильный ответ». Ах, если бы ребёнку дали послушать известный мотив с текстом Горина-Певзнера-Арканова «...я сижу pисую. Кpасок много у меня, — выбиpай любую. Я pаскpашу целый свет в самый свой любимый цвет»... Он имел бы представление, что на изображении рисуют только вандалы и сирень не рисуют *разными цветами*, а разным цветом (красок). Есть ли у кого верное представление о теме? Вообще, речь об авторе, или о картинке-раскраске? Всё глупо. В самом глупом положении — ребёнок.

Answer (score 0):

Текст содержит некоторые структурные и пунктуационные недочеты. Вот исправленная версия:

На этом изображении художник нарисовал СИРЕНИ разными цветами: белым, розовым, голубым. Ребёнку зачеркнули "изображение", сверху исправили на "репродукция", и зачеркнули "цветами", исправив на "красками".

Comment: Смысл исправлений неясен. Сам рисунок зачеркнут и дано пояснение: это не оригинальное изображение, а копия репродукции. Это понятно. Вероятно, рисовать нужно было красками, а не карандашами. Но какие слова были зачеркнуты? Рисунок имел название?

Comment: @Sharon  Зачёркнут не рисунок, а слова в предложении ребёнка: *"На этом изображении художник нарисовал сирень разными цветами: белым, розовым, голубым"*. Учитель посчитал, что вместо "изображения" нужно было написать "репродукция", а вместо "цветами" – "красками" (ну или "карандашами"). У автора вопроса всё понятно, в отличие от автора ответа.

Comment: Чтобы описать ситуацию, нужно ее понять. Как я могу найти РЕЧЕВУЮ ошибку (об этом вопрос), если  я не понимаю, о чем идет РЕЧЬ в этом тексте?

Comment: Я думаю, что это текст жалобы, которую родители прислали в наши образовательные структуры, контролирующие работу школ. Надо сказать, что учителя по ИЗО действительно ведут себя довольно-таки свободно и могут ставить плохие оценки не пойми за что.  А ведь детское творчество трудно оценить, впрочем, как и любое творчество)

Comment: Так что у меня вопросы ка ВСЕМ участникам темы, "сверху донизу".

Comment: @Sharon А я вас не понимаю :))  При чём тут ИЗО?  Ребёнок описывает картину или рисунок – в этом его творчество. А учитель, вероятнее всего по русскому, указал на его речевые ошибки.

Comment: Хорошо, ребенка исключаем из списка.  Дети цветы жизни)  Про составителей задания забыли: откуда взяли тему, что хотят?  Какой им нужен правильный ответ, по грамматике и пунктуации? А пунктуация зависит от смысла. Нет смысла –  нет решения. Но хотелось бы. конечно, увидеть правильный ответ. Мой же ответ такой: непонятен смысл сообщения.  В этом речевая ошибка.